# How can I access a property of an object in php by its index location

Tags: php, oop, object

In my code I want to access a property of an object in PHP using its index value, I can access it using the name but not using the index value:

I can do it like this :

```
foreach($object as $row)
{
echo $row['type'];
}
```

I want something like this:

```
foreach($object as $row)
{
echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: If you have used mysql_fetch_assoc then use mysql_fetch_array instead.

Comment: Yeah thats easy if we are using MySql as backend.  I m using mongo db at my back end ,

Comment: Would you like to describe your issue? Why do you need numeric index?

Comment: I am using mongo db as back end , so the attribute names may change for each document , So I need to access them via the index values and not index names

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$arr = array_values((array) $object);
foreach ($arr as $row) 
{
    echo $row[0];
}
```

**Updated:**

I think, in your case, you have to convert into array each row, like this:

```
foreach ($object as $row) 
{
    $row = array_values((array) $row);
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. I have already  tried it to convert object to array but the array has index as $a['type'] and not $a[0]

Comment: Do you have index `type` after call `array_values`?

Comment: My code is : $object =array($object);  foreach($object as $row ) { print_r($row); } Then the indexes are values{"_id", "values"} and not {0,1 etc}

Comment: @OmkarFrozen Wrap `$object =array($object)` into `array_values()` like in my answer

Comment: This is the error I get "Cannot use object of type MongoCursor as array."

Comment: Man I got the solution :   foreach ($object as $row) 
{
 $arr2 = array_values($row);
 echo $arr2[0];
   
}
 And it works!!!

Comment: $object is object and $row is a array. I got it using getType()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$object = array_values($object);

foreach($object as $row)
{
echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: This throws an warning: "Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given" and returns NULL